# Are PHP Variable Variable Variables possible. $$$a

Tags: php, variables

Php uses variable variables.
So

```
$a="hello";
$$a="oops";
echo($hello)
```

this gives us output:oops
My question is can Variable variables be used for more levels
like is $$$a defined?
will

```
$a="hello";
$$a="oops";
$$$a="she";
echo($oops);
```

give us output?? If yes to what level are variable variables possible?
If no why not????

Comment: If only there was a way to test this yourself...

Comment: What did your preliminary tests show?

Comment: @i-lo - The [so] Q&A format is not really geared towards discussions. Here questions must be specific enough to provide concrete answers to a real problem. You could maybe head on over to the [php chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) and have a discussion there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, and AFAIK they can be nested infinitely.

Please don't use these though, it's very rare that variable variables are a good idea, let alone variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variable variables.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the limit is quite high.

```
<?php

$depth = 1;
while (true) {
    echo "// At depth {$depth}\n";

    $prefix    = str_pad('', $depth, '$');
    $statement = "{$prefix}varvar = 'var{$depth}';\n";

    echo $statement;

    eval($statement);
    $depth++;
}
```

Only lightly tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can scope variables to the height of your stack. It is semi-infinite. You can declare variables inside variables until you run out of memory space. Then crazy crazy things will start to happen, and your program might crash (read really likely). Either way this type of scoping is not recommended.